# using @media for entire CSS

Tags: css, sass, media-queries, responsive

So to understand @media better, I have all my css code typed out.  To make my site responsive I use @media...  Does this mean that My CSS code will be double the length because all my code will go into the @media?

essentially I have to copy and paste my code and edit every element again to make it responsive?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, under media queries, you only need to write properties that you want to change as in this (copied) example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<style>

  h1{
    font-size:100px;
    color:red;
    background:black;
  }  
  @media(max-width:500px){
    h1{
      font-size:50px;
    }
  }
</style>



<body>
  
  
  <h1>Media Query Example</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And duplication makes CSS code hard to read and on a large scale, it makes the page slow, so you should not have duplicated CSS code.

Answer (score 0):

It is not like that, you don't have to write all the styles again under @media(){}, If you resize the window with styles excluding media query all styles will be still up there, the only thing that will happen is some content might overflow or for smaller screens we need smaller font-sizes or smaller image-size something like that, so we just add style to that specific element which we want to change for some specific sized screens. To better understand this, here's an example,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<style>

  h1{
    font-size:100px;
    color:red;
    background:black;
  }  
  @media(max-width:500px){
    h1{
      font-size:50px;
    }
  }
</style>



<body>
  
  
  <h1>Media Query Example</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Try running above snippet and see how size of the text changes of screen size lesser than  or equal to 500px.
Here you can see under style tag under media query i only applied font-size, other two property i.e background and color is inherited.

Answer (score 0):

No. Doubled code structures are not a good idea.

The mechanic off `@media` is really simple. Stylings with `@media` has a higher specifity and overwrite stylings without. And `@media min-width: 800px` is more specific to screens up from `800px` than `@media min-width 500px` and overwrites the stylings set by the second one.

Knowing that you are able to organize your css.

Not running demo example to explain the idea:

```
// first common code for all elements
// should work on mobile phones (= mobile first)

div {

   // stylings for all views
   // that's most off your code
   // positions, colors, general structure-settings, font-styling (without sizes) ...
   font-family: sans-serif;
   color: gray;
   background: white;
   border: 1px solid yellow;
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   ...
   ...
   ... and anything else

   // stylings working on mobile
   // will be overwritten to other views
   // that are almost sizings
   width: 100% // = only one column on mobiles
   padding: 4px; // = small on mobile
   font-size: 9px;
   line-height: 11px;  
   ...   
}

// now overwrite only the classes which changes for tablets
@media(min-width: 768px) {
   div {
      width: 50%; // = 2 columns on tablet
      padding: 8px;
      font-size: 11px;
      line-height: 14px;
   }
}

// now overwrite only the classes which changes for smaller desktops
@media(min-width: 992px) {
   div {
      width: 25%; // = 4 columns on tablet
      padding: 15px;

      // note: font-size and line-height doesn't change
      // same as on tablets

   }
}

// do that for every breakpoint you need
// i.e. add large/wide screens 
// i.d. add tablet portrait landscape between tablet and desktop smaller screens
// ...
```

TYPICAL USED BREAKPOINTS:

Note: not every project needs all breakpoints
simple / more easy project uses i.e.:
`X-Small`, `Medium`, `Large`

... depends on your design and how many work is reserved for the project

```
X-Small (i.e. mobile portrait)
Small   ≥576px   (i.e. mobile landscape)
Medium  ≥768px   (i.e. tablets)
Large   ≥992px   (i.e. small desktop, tablets landscape)
Extra large  ≥1200px   (up from here wide screen with hgh resolution, HD, 4 HD, ...)
Extra extra large  ≥1400px
```

---

*Update: added typical breakpoints.*